# Mini-Toolbar is missing formatting options in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm running Microsoft Office 365 Excel Version 1911, Monthly Channel (Targeted) on Windows 10. Recently the "Mini-Toolbar" that appears when you right click a CELL no longer contains all options. Missing are: Increase Font, Decrease Font, Accounting Number Format, Percent Style, Comma Style, Merge & Center, Font Color, Border Styles, Increase Decimal, Decrease Decimal, and Format Painter. The larger Quick Access toolbar also has an added selection at the very bottom that indicates "Additional Cell Actions". I compared these toolbars to those on my laptop running Microsoft Office 365 Excel Version 1910, and they are as per normal.

This sounds to me like an Office Update issue, so I followed the Microsoft instructions to revert to an earlier version of Click-to-Run at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic but, surprise, surprise, the process ends with "Something went wrong" and no reversion.

Has anyone else encountered and/or found a solution to this Excel issue?

Comment: My own Office 2016 is subscription, right up to date and right clicking on a cell produces a large list and the mini-toolbar on top. Perhaps did it just move ?

Comment: The mini-toolbar is there, it's just truncated. It no longer contains the essential formatting options I liked to have handy. I read on a Microsoft site that the mini-toolbar is not editable, so I don't think it was anything I did. This occurred just after an update to Version 1911 (Build 12228.20290)

Comment: Mine has about a dozen tools and pull downs for numerous tools. So it appears it has been changed in the most recent build.

Comment: A member from the Microsoft Community confirmed this change occurred in Version 1911 and continues into Version 1912.I've obviously halted all updates to my laptop Version 1910, but I'd still like to know how to revert my PC Excel Version from 1911 to 1910.

Comment: My thinking is that we should adapt as the changes will remain and go forward for some indeterminate time until they change it again. I have only once done what you want, a couple of years ago, and because of a bug: First, go to Office Account and disable Updates
Next, open an Admin Command Prompt and enter the following command:

"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe"  … 
/update user updatetoversion="you need to know what version"

Comment: Hi John. I did exactly what you suggested several days ago, to no avail - same "Something went wrong" result. I have re-created the missing options on my Quick Access Toolbar, but now I need to show it below the ribbon, because the number of items is too large to show above it without a secondary menu (>>). I can't understand WHY someone at Microsoft would think this Mini-Toolbar change would go unnoticed, and I certainly don't understand why they felt it necessary to drastically reduce features their users have grown accustomed to.

Comment: I looked at my own QA setup and if the number of items gets to big, it will not go below. So we just have to adapt. I cannot see another way given the volume of updates coming at us

Comment: I see: Roll over and die. Sounds just like what Microsoft would want us to do. John, your comments concerning the QA bar are misleading, if not totally false. I have ALL the Mini-Toolbar options on that QA toolbar BELOW the ribbon, with much room left to spare. I do not understand why you would want to promulgate this type of disinformation.

Comment: Unless you, and this exchange, have ties to Microsoft.

Comment: I did not try a secondary row - just one for my own convenience. I was not trying to mislead you in any way.